# SU-48 footprint

Tags: packages, footprint

[This datasheet](http://www.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/pdf/48688/AD/ADG732BSU.html) specifies the packages for the components, but not the associated footprints.

The package of interest for me is SU-48. The [obvious search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=su-48+footprint&aq=2&oq=SU-48+&aqs=chrome.3.57j0l3j62l2.3039&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=su-48+footprint&oq=su-48+foot&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i30.1669.2211.2.2972.5.5.0.0.0.0.98.363.5.5.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.omjeuN0N3oQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.ZWU&fp=4983e0025ed4ff4f&biw=1389&bih=875) brings me to [this outline](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/packages/470644706845302410119987SU48_7x7.pdf), but still no footprint.

Where can I find footprint information for the SU-48 package?

Comment: Are you looking for an Eagle footprint file, or KiCad, or some other format?

Comment: I'm looking for the dimensions of the pads to enter in the Cadence Allegro software.

Comment: It looks like a standard TQFP48 footprint. I've got one I created for the Pulsonix software I use, pads are 0.3 mm x 1.6 mm. It was probably for a home-made PCB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite what Olin says, it's actually not unusual at all for datasheets to provide footprints. It's the first place I look. However, this part comes in standard TQFP and LFCPS packages, and either your PCB software can generate these with a wizard (Altium does) or you can look up the footprint online:

[Microchip Packaging Specification document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/PackagingSpec/00049AR.pdf) has some.

The key thing you want to search for is TQFP or LFCPS (depending on the package you choose).

Comment: OP mentions that the SU-48 i.e. TQFP48 is his package of interest, simplifying the matter.

Comment: The Allegro software does have a package symbol wizard, but I still need to specify the padstack manually.

Comment: Actually I didn't say that footprints in datasheets are unusual, just that they are of little value for most ordinary parts.  The datasheet writers don't know what your process is, whether you want to build for field service, what kind of solder you will use, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution, since the part in question is a standard **TQFP48** 50 mil pitch package, is to make your own footprint for it.

If that's too much work, look for an Allegro footprint for any other TQFP48 with the same dimensions, and use that.

You can safely ignore the SU-48 designator, just don't ignore the package dimensions.

Also, Olin's answer provides valuable insight into how much slop is suggested on the inner and outer sides of the pin pads.

Answer (score -1):

Except in unusual circumstances, it's not the job of datasheets to tell you what the pads should be on your board.  They tell you what the device does and it's shape and tolerances, and it's your job to interface with that.  Some datasheets do include a footprint as a suggestion, but those don't take into account your system level issues and are therefore usually worthless.  There can be exceptions to this for very high frequency parts, keepout areas for RF, and high dissipation parts with special thermal needs.

So go back to the datasheet and figure out where you want the pads to be, considering your design rules, assembly procedures, need for debugging, etc.  Others can't know your constraints, so getting a footprint or whole package definition from someone else is asking for trouble.  Usually it's as much work verifying someone else's package definition meets your requirements than to just make one the way you want in the first place.

When there are no other constraints, I usually add 20 mils to the outside ends of pads.  That allows for a little alignment slop and can make scope probing a little easier.  On the inside, you don't need to add as much, like 5-10 mils.  Look at the datasheet carefully and keep worst case tolerances in mind.  If you have a assymetric shape, keep in mind how the surface tension of the molten solder will pull the part.  Don't add so much slop to the end of a large tab on one side, for example, that the surface tension pulls smaller pins off their pads on the other side.